# Can i cover Great Stuff foam with Flex Seal tar to protect the great stuff from UV damage?

Tags: basement, spray-foam

Cabin has a 'fake walls' to cover and close the gap from the ground to the actual structure, like a trailer skirt.  fake wall (rock wall) is made of rubble and mortar.  In several sections the wall has fallen back or sunk as it is not set below the frost line.  This is not structural, just a facade.

I have successfully used Great Stuff expanding foam  on the entire basement rim joist with pest block to the top of the rubble wall.

I'm  using Great Stuff as a type of mortar to hold the rock wall together.  I see already the Great Stuff is fading from gray to tan due to UV damage.  Can I cover the Great Stuff with Flex Seal to protect it?  Running out of temperature for paint.  Normally paint would be an appropriate cover.

When using Great Stuff outside, it gets damaged by UV, even in a shaded location.  It is recommended to paint it to protect it from fading and eventual disintegration.

Comment: "*but I see already the foam is fading*" Fading?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make both the situation and the solutions you are discussing more clear?  A photo or two might help a lot here.

Comment: what is great stuff? ... if it is a brand name of a product, then the name should be capitalized in your post

Comment: "*I'm using Great Stuff as a type of mortar to hold the rock wall together.*" That is not what expanding foam is designed to do. It fills gaps, it may not be the best thing to bind rubble together with. Spray it Flex Seal, what have you got to loose at this point.

Comment: The theory was that Great Stuff makes black foam for in water use for landscape waterfalls and similar.  But I cant get that at a local store.  So I used  Pest Block Great Stuff and it does anchor the rubble in place.  Keep in mind, this is an existing rubble (random stone) wall with mortar. 
For now, the foam did what I wanted, basement is dark.  This is a tremendous improvement over last winter.

Answer (score 2):

### Use paint for that

Alkyd (oil) paint is applicable as low as 40F -- as long as you carefully watch the weather so you will not have condensing humidity before the paint skins over (ceases to be tacky).  I find Rustoleum oil-base paints are a reliable, fast drying and readily available choice.

Even Rustoleum primer will buy you a year or two of UV protection until you overcoat it (and latex is fine for that).

### Tar is a bad idea, generally

Tar is slick as a quickie repair, but it also fails in a year or two.  When it does, about the only repair option you have is more tar, since nothing else will stick to it.  After 2-3 tar repair it becomes too crinkled and curdled that it won't seal even with more tar.  At that point, the whole kit-and-kaboodle must be scraped off, hauled away as construction waste, and re-done with new material.

So only use tar as a temporary repair on something you'll be replacing soon anyway.

And never, ever, ever, ever use it on a rubber roof!

Comment: I had used some kind of tar a long time ago on a thin crack and concur with Harper - Reinstate Monica's comment, it gets hard and crusty and doesn't last.